# Python decrement the variable inside for loop

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

i converted my java code into a python code and how to decrement the variable inside of the for loop in the python? I try to decrease the index by 1 if it is inside the if statement, but apparently I can't do that. Is there any other way that I can decrease i in a for loop?

Java Code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Movie " + i + " of " + 3 + " : ");
            String inputMovie = sc.nextLine();
            if (inputMovie.equals("")) 
            {
                System.out.println("Please input a movie name.");
                System.out.println("");
                i--;
            }

            else
                movies.offer("'"+inputMovie+"'");
        }
```

Python Code:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    inputMovie=input("Enter Movie " + str(i) + " of " + str(3) + " : ")
    if inputMovie=="":
        print("Please input a movie name")
        print("")
        i-=1
        pass
    else:
        movies.append(inputMovie)
    pass
```

Output: well if we look at the output it is still incrementing not decrementing the i

```
Enter Movie 1 of 3 :
Please input a movie name

Enter Movie 2 of 3 :
Please input a movie name

Enter Movie 3 of 3 :
Please input a movie name
```

Comment: use ```while``` instead of ```if``` till desired input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't let you alter the iterator in a `for` loop. As soon as the next iteration of the loop comes by, the iterator will be the next value of the iterable.

This is also because `range` doesn't behave like an actual Java-like `for` loop. Instead, it keeps generating numbers within the range (you can see this by typing `list(range(10))` in a Python interpreter, it will make a list of numbers from 0 to 9.

If you want to modify the iterator, you should go old-school with a `while` loop instead:

```py
i = 1
while i <= 3:
    inputMovie=input("Enter Movie " + str(i) + " of " + str(3) + " : ")
    if inputMovie=="":
        print("Please input a movie name")
        print("")
        i-=1
    else:
        movies.append(inputMovie)
    i = i + 1
```

This should do the same as your Java code, as I'm just moving the three instructions from the Java `for` loop to their places. Notice `pass` is not required as it is a statement with no effect.

For the sake of optimization, let me say you don't really need to decrement the iterator, just avoid **incrementing it** instead. I keep this solution separate from the original answer since it is a significant deviation from your original design:

```py
i = 1
while i <= 3:
    inputMovie=input("Enter Movie " + str(i) + " of " + str(3) + " : ")
    if inputMovie=="":
        print("Please input a movie name")
        print("")
    else:
        movies.append(inputMovie)
        i = i + 1
```

All I've done is remove the decrement and push the increment to the `else` block so it is only run if a movie name has been input.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a `while` statement

"Unfortunately" the `for` loop will keep "memory" and reassign to the next value at each iteration

```
i = 1
while i < 4:
    inputMovie = input("Enter Movie " + str(i) + " of " + str(3) + " : ")
    if inputMovie == "":
        print("Please input a movie name")
        print("")
        i-=1
    else:
        movies.append(inputMovie)
        i+=1
```

the `pass` instruction is irrelevant, you can omit that

[pass statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html)

Answer (score 1):

`range(low,high)` generates a sequence consisting of elements starting from `low` and ending at `high-1`. That's why your `i-=1` doesn't work, since I is iterating in that list.
The easiest alternative here would be to use a `while` loop.

```py
while i<target:
    if something:
        #do something
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop in Python is more like for-each. So the loop value(i) will get updated to the next value regardless of the changes/updates in the loop.

A better way to do this would be to use a while loop.

```
i = 1
while i <= 3:
    inputMovie = input("Enter Movie " + str(i) + " of " + str(3) + " : ")
    if inputMovie=="":
        print("Please input a movie name")
        print("")
        i-=1
        pass
    else:
        movies.append(inputMovie)
        i+=1
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your `range()` function correctly. In order to decrement the loop you can use `while` loop or you can change your algorithm and set the `for` loop but now what you can do is if you can select the range functions step value to -1.  Please try it to check the code coz i also have the same question in mind like you.